# How to remove optional responses from Facebook login response using swift?

Tags: ios, swift, facebook

I am trying to integrate Facebook login for my application. I have done everything but after login response I am getting Optionals("Value"). I need to get only values for name, email,etc

```
if((FBSDKAccessToken.current()) != nil){
     FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me",
                       parameters: ["fields": "id, name, first_name, last_name, picture.type(large), email, gender"])
        .start(completionHandler: { (connection, result, error) -> Void in

            if error != nil {
                 // Some error checking here
            }
            else if let userDataDict = result as? NSDictionary {
               if let id = userDataDict["id"] as? String {
                   print(id)
                   UserDefaults.standard.set(id, forKey: "id")
               }
            })
}
```

Comment: That's the way to get it, the values come in that form. in order the unwrap them, do with `name` and `email` the same you did with `id`.

Comment: but it will make many If. Really, is it good way of get it? @Tal Cohen

Answer (score 0):

```
let loginManager = LoginManager()
    loginManager.logIn([ .publicProfile, .email], viewController: self) { loginResult in
        switch loginResult {
        case .failed(let error):
            print(error)
        case .cancelled:
            print("User cancelled login.")
        case .success(let grantedPermissions, let declinedPermissions, let accessToken):
            let graphRequest:FBSDKGraphRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields":"first_name, last_name, email, picture.type(large), birthday"])
            graphRequest.start(completionHandler: { (connection, result, error) -> Void in

                if ((error) != nil)
                {
                    print("Error: \(error)")
                }else
                {
                    let data:[String:AnyObject] = result as! [String : AnyObject]
                    //                        print(data)
                    var parameters = [String: Any]()
                    parameters.email = data["email"]?.description
                    parameters.facebook_id = data["id"]?.description
                }
            })
        }
    }
```

Some private accounts may not give you access to all the info you need such as email, so you have to do those nil checks buddy

Answer (score 0):

just use this sign to remove optional from response just like

```
print(id!)
```